# App crashes on submission to Apple App store while it was working in debug mode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

This is the crash report i am getting. App store guys said while clicking on any functionality crashes the app but this is not the case, in debug mode everything is working fine.

```
 Full Stack Trace:
 0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x196f9c0b8 _objc_retain + 24
 1   KitchenFast                         0x1000e26f0 __mh_execute_header + 452336
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x18a55b5b4 <redacted> + 20
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x18a4a8104 __CFXNotificationPost + 2064
 4   Foundation                          0x18b03a748 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72

 5   KitchenFast                         0x1000e1608 __mh_execute_header + 448008
 6   Foundation                          0x18b1285cc <redacted> + 328
 7   CoreFoundation                      0x18a567644 <redacted> + 24
 8   CoreFoundation                      0x18a5669a0 <redacted> + 256
 9   CoreFoundation                      0x18a564c38 <redacted> + 632
 10  CoreFoundation                      0x18a4a5c20 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
 11  GraphicsServices                    0x190145c0c _GSEventRunModal + 168
 12  UIKit                               0x18d5d6fdc _UIApplicationMain + 1156
 13  KitchenFast                         0x10007d700 __mh_execute_header + 38656
 14  libdyld.dylib                       0x197577aa0 <redacted> + 4
```

Comment: What object are you passing with the postNotification method??

Comment: you can run it in release mode and see what happened

Comment: Do you have any #debug compiler directives? Search the project for #debug.  Also.. Bryan is right.  Build it for adhoc distribution and load that one.  You can even check your NSLog's using the console in Xcode.

Comment: I am not using postNotification method. I have run in using ad-hoc distribution and it was working fine.

Comment: App store guys rejected with a reason that it crashes on iOS 7.1.1

Comment: Mine was rejected a week ago with a similar issue and the exact same reason.

Comment: Did u solve the issue?

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report and frame #1 and #5 would show your own code that triggers this crash. You need the full crash report and the exact dSYM that was created with the app binary to do this. There is plenty of documentation here on how to do this (even manually).